# gather all video links from a youtube users webpage

Tags: java

I am trying to pull all the links off a youtube users uploads page but I am only getting the first 30 videos, I want to be able to get all 56 videos and I would like to be able to continue using jsoup if possible.

```
    Document BeInspired = Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaKZDEMDdQc8t6GzFj1_TDw/videos").get();
        Elements links = BeInspired.select("a[href]");

        for (Element link : links) {
            if (link.attr("href").contains("/watch?v=")) {
                if (videos.contains(link.attr("href"))) {

                } else {
                    videos.add(link.attr("href"));
                }
            }

            System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
        }
```

This is the code I am currently using.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I want to get the other 30 or so videos left on that page

Comment: the url I am using has 56 videos on it I believe, but I only get the first 30 using this code